# Estimate for the integral using convexity bound

Tags: riemann-zeta

I'm reading the proof of Hardy and Littlewood's theorem in the book *Analytic Number Theory*, written by Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski (p. 547):

> **Theorem (Hardy and Littlewood):** Let $N_0(T)$ be the number of non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $s=\sigma+i t$, with $0<t\leq T$. Then 
>   $$N_0(T)\gg T. $$

The idea of the proof is clear and is based in two lemmas.
Define 
$$f(u)=\frac{g(1/2+iu)}{|g(1/2+iu)|}\zeta(1/2+iu),$$
and
$$I(t)=\int_t^{t+\Delta}f(u)\,du,$$
where $\Delta>0$ a fixed number and
$$g(s)=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2).$$
The book asserts:

> **Lemma:** Let $\Delta\geq 1$. Then, if $T\geq \Delta^6$
>   $$\int_T^{2T}|I(t)|^2\, dt\ll \Delta T,$$
>   where the implied constant is absolute.

In certain point (the beginning) the authors say 
$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_T^{2T}f(t+u_1)\overline{f}(t+u_2)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\\
&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_T^{2T}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2+O(\Delta^3 T^{1/2}).\\
\end{align*}$$
This step is not clear for me. The book say this follows by use of the convexity bound $|\zeta(1/2+it)|\ll |t|^{1/4}$, and the expressions suggest the change $t+u_1\to t$ which make appear the integrand but change the limits of integration. What I got
$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_T^{2T}f(t+u_1)\overline{f}(t+u_2)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\\
&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T+u_1}^{2T+u_1}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2.\\
&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{2T}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\\
&\quad\quad+\left(\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T+u_1}^{2T+u_1}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\right.\\
&\quad\quad\left.-\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{2T}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\right)\\
&=:M+E.
\end{align*}$$
Hence I need to prove
$$\begin{align*}
E&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T+u_1}^{2T+u_1}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\\
&\quad\quad-\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{2T}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\ll \Delta^3 T^{1/2}.
\end{align*}$$

> **Question:** How to prove this estimate using the Convexity bound?

It can be possible that this is not the approach, the thing is that I have time trying but didn't get the desired result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a solution. It's a very simple calculation. Write $E$ as
\begin{align*}
E&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{T+u_1}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\\
&\quad\quad+\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{2T}^{2T+u_1}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2=:E_1+E_2.
\end{align*}
We will bound each one by separate.
\begin{align*}
E_1&=\int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{T+u_1}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2\\
&\leq \int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{T+\Delta}f(t)\overline{f}(t+u_2-u_1)\,dt\,du_1\,du_2,\\
\end{align*}
by convexity
\begin{align*}
E_1&\ll \int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{T+\Delta}|t|^{1/4}|t+u_2-u_1|^{1/4}\,dt\,du_1\,du_2,\\
&\ll \int_0^\Delta\int_0^\Delta\int_{T}^{T+\Delta}|T+\Delta|^{1/4}|T+2\Delta|^{1/4}\,dt\,du_1\,du_2,\\
&\ll \Delta^3|T+\Delta|^{1/4}|T+2\Delta|^{1/4}.
\end{align*}
Since $T\geq \Delta^6$ then $T+\Delta$ and $T+2\Delta$ are $\ll T$. Hence the error term. In the same fashion we can prove $E_2\ll \Delta^3 T^{1/2}$.